# Bigquery non-null(geographypoint) in grouped dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to pick non-null(geographypoint) from my grouped dataset. The max function gives the following error.

> MAX is not defined for arguments of type GEOGRAPHY at [65:11]

Consider the sample data:

```
╔════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║id                  ║Point                         ║
╠════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣             
║1                   ║POINT(-79.3123031 43.6839641) ║       
║1                   ║null                          ║      
╚════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

I need to pick out the non null value from the grouped data.
For numeric/string values, we can use `max`
Is there a way to tackle this for Geography data in bigquery?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to pick out the non null value from the grouped data

Consider below approach

```
select id, any_value(point) point
from data
where not point is null
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

MAX is not meaningful for spatial types because they are not simple values. I think you need to use the [Geography functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions) and either

- Extract a simple datatype (using a function like ST_X, or ST_AREA for example), and then you could use a MAX meaningfully to find for example the MAX longitude or the MAX area
- Use a function like ST_BOUNDARY if you're looking for something like a spatial boundary from multiple GEOGRAPHY values

Comment: I edited the question a bit. Let me know your thoughts please! Thank you.

Comment: Gotcha, I see the updates. In your example there's only one Point within that id group which is non null, so you are allowed to just add a `WHERE Point IS NOT NULL`. But assuming the normal case is there are _many_ Points within an id group, what is it that would make one of the Points the "maximum" within that group? Could be furthest North, furthest East, furthest South, etc? It comes back to using ST_X, for example, to get a number from each Point. Once you have a simple value you can find the MAX...